# Combine two distinct function definitions - one curried, one standard

Tags: ios, swift, currying

Been playing around with curried functions in swift, and I'm trying to write a function now that can be written as:

```
sum(1,2) //or
sum(1)(2) //both equal 3
```

This is easy to do with two function definitions:

```
// curried - usage: sum(1)(2) or sum(1)
func sum(a: Int) -> (Int -> Int) {
    return { b in a + b }
}

// regular - usage: sum(1,2)
func sum(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
```

I've been trying to combine these into one function that could be called either way, but I think I'm either stumped or there's no solution. I tried reworking it with generic types, but still ran into the problem of the number of parameters, even with optionals.

So, any ideas on how to combine these, or is it not possible with swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you are trying to do this, so I may have missed the point entirely, but this is the closest I can get to it...

```
enum IntOrFunction {
    case Number(Int)
    case Function((Int -> Int))
    var function: (Int -> Int) {
        switch self {
        case .Function(let f):
            return f
        case .Number(let i):
            return { _ in return i }
        }
    }
}

func sum(params: Int...) -> IntOrFunction {
    if params.count == 1 {
        let a = params[0]
        return .Function({ b in a + b })
    } else {
        return .Number(params.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1}))
    }
}

let a = sum(1,2) // "Number(3)"
let b = sum(1) // "Function((Function))"
let c = b.function(3) // "4"
```

Comment: Honestly no point. Just a friday afternoon thing. Hm, maybe your sum function with generic types would work.

Comment: The annoying thing is that I had to write the `function` method to extract the enum's associated value - there must be an easier way to access associated values...?

Answer (score 1):

Currying is a method of translating function with multiple parameters into sequence of function. So no, there is no way to do that. Only thing you can do is to create "interface"

```
func sum(a: Int) -> (Int -> Int) {
    return { b in a + b }
}

func sum(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return sum(a)(b)
}
```

Comment: yea thats basically what i did, still 2 function definitions. cool alternative though!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
func *<A, B, C>(lhs: A -> B -> C, rhs: (A, B)) -> C {
    return lhs(rhs.0)(rhs.1)
}

func sum(a: Int)(_ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

sum(1)(2)
sum*(1, 2)
```